# Null character behavior c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s = "hello";

  cout << s[5] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In the above code, if I print `s[5]`, it correctly prints a `NULL` character. But if I change the code to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char[] s = {'a','b','c','d','e'};

  cout << s[5] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It doesn't print a `NULL` character but something random. If I store the string as a `string` or as a `char*`, then the behavior is in tune with what I expect.

But if I explicitly declare the character array, how does the compiler know when the array ends? Does the size of the array gets stored at compile time?

Comment: `char[] s = {'a','b','c','d','e'};` This construct only stores the characters you specify and nothing else; there is no null terminator.

Comment: compiler looks at the number of static chars that you've provided and finds out its size. naturally if no static chars were declared, you would need to provide a size

Comment: It should be `char s[]`,  not `char[] s`.

Answer (score 2):

String literals and `std::string`s store null terminated strings.

But an array of 5 `char` declared like:

```
char s[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
```

contains only 5 `char`,  no null terminator.

But the compiler *does*  know the size of `s`. It is part of the type of `s`. It has no convenient `.size()` function like `std::string`, `std::vector` or `std::array` does but you can get it by doing:

```
sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0])
```

Or more safely in C++11:

```
std::extent<decltype(s)>::value
```

Or in C++17:

```
std::size(s)
```

([demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/r9DfUjkwhdIySc7p))

Arrays have a habit of decaying to pointers though and then there is no way of getting the size,  you have to keep track of it yourself. Which is why `std::string`, `std::vector` or `std::array` is preferred in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are null-terminated, and `const char*` are treated the same way as Strings are. When you declare a array with a size it's put on the stack and the compiler doesn't know the size. Array out-of-bounds exceptions aren't determined during compile time.

Comment: The compiler _does_ know the size of an array. It is just not doing an out of bounds check for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `char[] s = {'a','b','c','d','e'};`, it will store characters mentioned and nothing else.

> if I explicitly declare the character array, how does the compiler know when the array ends?

size is determined by number of characters provided by you.

> Does the size of the array gets stored at compile time?

no, the size of array is determined by memory blocks allocated to it. (It is not stored separately in memory, if that's what you meant)

And when you use this `string s = "hello";`, strings are always null terminated.

Comment: If you declare an array like `char s[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};` then the size of `s` is atored at compile time. If is part of the type of `s`. See for example [`std::extent`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent)

Comment: He is asking about does it gets stored

Comment: What do you mean by "stored"? You can get the size from the type so yes it is "stored". e.g you can write a ranged based for loop: `for(char c : s){...}`

Comment: @ChrisDrew Updated the answer, is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

the string class in c++ has the constructor which by itself adds the null character to the string passed to it if not explicitly added. But while using char it only stores the content passed to it (i.e) if you want to have a null character you have to explicitly add in the declaration or the definition of that char.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is `char s[] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};`, so it will not put the `\0` at the end of your `char array`. It will put the `\0` with three methods below:

```
1. char s[] = {'a','b','c','d','e', '\0'};
2. char s[] = "abcde";
3. string s = "abcde";
```

So if you use any of  the three above, you will get a `NULL` character.

Answer (score 0):

"how does the compiler know when the array ends ?": the compiler knows how many elements the array has, from its declaration, and this information is available through the sizeof operator.

Anyway C-style arrays have virtually no size, as they are implicitly turned to pointers when passed as arguments, and their length is dropped (IMO a major flaw in the design of the C language). Overflow avoidance is your responsibility.

For this reason, you mustn't use a cout << statement if your string isn't null-terminated.